# Why is Application.WorkbookNewChart event not firing on the new chart types such as Sunburst, Treemap?

Tags: excel, charts, vsto

In my Excel VSTO plugin I created Treemap chart, Sunburst chart manually. I had a break point in my event handler for : Application.WorkbookNewChart  . This break point was never hit conmfirming that my NewChart event is not even firing for these new chart types. It does get fired if I use the old types such as Pie Chart, Bar chart etc. Can someone please help?